# Confused about mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to get redux to work correctly with my app. It seems to be working to some extent. However, the render function does not seem to update when data gets returned.

In trying to test this I have done the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
        console.log(state.correct_property_name)
        console.log(state)
    return {
        data: state.correct_property_name
    };
};
```

In this case, the console.log for `correct_data_name` returns as an empty array: []. The dispatch does not seem to get called at all.

However, if I change the last line in the above code to have an incorrect property name, the console.log does work, dispatch is called, but my render function does not reload:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
        console.log(state.correct_property_name)
        console.log(state)
    return {
        data: state.wrong_property_name
    };
};
```

**Question:**

Why does changing the last line to the wrong property name suddenly cause the console.log to show the data?

Here are the remaining lines in the file if that is useful:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    fetchData() {
        dispatch(mySpecialActions.fetchMySpecialData());
    }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyClassName);
```

**Actions:**

```
import Axios from 'axios';

const apiUrl = '/api/my_data/';
export const fetchMySpecialDataSuccess = (correct_property_name) => {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_MY_SPECIAL_DATA_SUCCESS',
    correct_property_name
  }
};


export const fetchMySpecialData = () => {

  console.log("TEST ONE")
  return (dispatch) => {
        console.log("DISPATCH")
    return Axios.get(apiUrl)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("DATA")

        dispatch(fetchMySpecialDataSuccess(response.data))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("ERROR")
        console.log(error)
        throw(error);
      });
  };
};
```

The comments in the actions file only display if I set the last line in my main file to `data: state.incorrect_property_name`. To me this is saying that it is not even invoking the action when I specify the correct property name. But does invoke the action when I specify a fake property name.

**Reducer:**

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes'

export const mySpecialDataReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.FETCH_MY_SPECIAL_DATA_SUCCESS:
          return action.correct_property_name;
    default:
        console.log("DEFAULT STATE")
          return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you add your reducer & your actions?

Comment: @Melchia I have added them for you. Thank you.

Comment: I can't really see anything sticking out that's obviously wrong. Did you check redux dev tools and see the state change on the actions? Did you try logging the object as a string: `console.log(JSON.stringify(state.correct_property_name,undefined,2))`.

Comment: Try changing your state in your reducer to an object instead of array. `export const mySpecialDataReducer = (state = {}, action) => {`